# How to make activity custom size?

Tags: android, android-activity

I am working with android. I had created an activity and call another activity from current activity.I need to convert second activity in small size just like a button and I can access both activities at a time and make action on both activities at a time. Is it possible to make activity custom sized ?? please help me with your suggestion. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You have started an intent from the first activity and move to the second activity.Now you are in the context of the second activity .You cannot see your first activity by reducing the size of the second activity.

Comment: I used custom transparent background to 2nd one so now i can see both but i cant make action on the 1st one

Comment: Im not sure whether you are looking for somthing like this http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/multi-pane-layouts.html

Comment: Even if u have applied transparent backgorund Still you are in the second activity. So you cannot perfrom any action on the first activity components

Comment: my second activity is sliderdrawer with an image button. so that I can slide to new view when i am in 1st activity. This is I am looking for :)

Comment: You cannot do this with multiple activities.You should b looking at Android Fragments.

Comment: Actually I want to create library for a slider adview. So I need to provide slider adview to developer who integrate my library.So is it possible to make such custom slider view to another app?? how to call only slider to that app??

Comment: please help me I am searching for the last 1 month for this solution :(

Comment: I didnt get you exactly .Slider adview ?? http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/  Is that you looking for?

Comment: ya slider view . but is it possible to hide and unhide slider for diff activity ??

Comment: Did you check the link in the last comment? http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

Comment: you can do that with fragment,i guess this will help you. http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html